# How to use nltk3 for python33?

Tags: nltk, python-3.3

I successfully installed NLTK 2.0.4, but when I tried to download the NLTK packages, i.e.

```
nltk.download('stopwords')
```

it doesn't work, so I am trying to install an updated version of NLTK for python 3 but it gives this error:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python33\site-packages\nltk\_
nit__.py", line 37
    except IOError, ex:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to install NLTK for python33?

Answer (score 3):

First install `python3-pip` then use it to install pyyaml

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install pyyaml
$ wget http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/nltk-3.0a3.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf nltk-3.0a3.tar.gz
$ cd nltk-3.0a3/
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
$ python3
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> print(brown.sents()[0])
['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', 'Friday', 'an', 'investigation', 'of', "Atlanta's", 'recent', 'primary', 'election', 'produced', '``', 'no', 'evidence', "''", 'that', 'any', 'irregularities', 'took', 'place', '.']
```