# Install nltk 3.0 on Ubuntu 13.10 using tar.gz download

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nltk

I want to install nltk 3.0 on Ubuntu 13.10.

I have been running Ubuntu for a few weeks (first time I am using Linux) and I have just downloaded python 3.4.0 - 3.3 is also on Ubuntu since it was installed with the operating system. Python 2.5+ is also preinstalled and I actually have the nltk (not 3.0) installed using the terminal and can use this in my python 2 idle, but not my python 3 idle as expected.

However, and my newbieness will shine here. I have no idea where 3.4 installed, so I don't know where to unzip the nltk-3.0a3.tar.gz !!

I am fine with using the terminal to download if needed, I just don't know how with nltk 3.4 either.

Comment: you have two way: 1. `apt-get install python-nltk`  2. `easy_install install nltk`

Comment: that will install nltk version 3.0?

Comment: i don't know check it. `apt-cache show python-ntlk`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [How to use nltk3 for python33?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327732/how-to-use-nltk3-for-python33/22330200#22330200)

First install `python3-pip` then use it to install pyyaml

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install pyyaml
$ wget http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/nltk-3.0a3.tar.gz
$ tar -xzvf nltk-3.0a3.tar.gz
$ cd nltk-3.0a3/
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
$ python3
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> print(brown.sents()[0])
['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', 'Friday', 'an', 'investigation', 'of', "Atlanta's", 'recent', 'primary', 'election', 'produced', '``', 'no', 'evidence', "''", 'that', 'any', 'irregularities', 'took', 'place', '.']
```

Comment: You can install directly from the url of nltk too. `pip install http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/nltk-3.0a3.tar.gz#egg=nltk`